# How to schedule a powershell script for automating wack process through windows scheduler?

Tags: powershell, scripting, batch-file, scheduler

I am able to execute the below command from PowerShell prompt and command prompt, but I am unable to schedule it using windows scheduler.

powershell script code:

```
appcert.exe test -apptype metrostyle -packagefullname abc_somename -reportoutputpath C:\result.xml
```

`appcert.exe` is a Microsoft provided exe for performing certification test on my Windows 8 application. I did the following:

1. I am making a file `ABC.ps1` with code:

   ```
   appcert.exe test -apptype metrostyle -packagefullname abc_somename -reportoutputpath C:\result.xml
   ```
2. I create a batch file `PQR.bat` with this code:

   ```
   powershell -command "& 'PathOfABC\ABC.ps1' "
   ```
3. I am scheduling it through Windows scheduler.

While creating task under actions tab, I choose following details:

- Action: Start a program
- Program/Script: Path to the batch file
- Start in: Path of the folder containing the batch file

And I schedule it to run every 15 mins. The Task completes, but I do not see any `result.xml` in my C drive. Can you point me how can I schedule this batch file to execute every 15 mins?

Answer (score 0):

Use `powershell -File "C:\path\to\ABC.ps1"` to run powershell scripts. Or put the `appcert.exe` command directly in a batch script. Running a batch script to run a PowerShell script to run an executable is pointless.

Assuming that `appcert.exe` creates `C:\result.xml` when you run the script manually:

- Do you have set the execution policy to at least `RemoteSigned`?
- Does the user running the task have the `Log on as batch job` privilege?
- Is the scheduled task configured to run with highest privileges (assuming that UAC is enabled)?

Did you try adding some debugging code to the script, e.g.

```
appcert.exe test ... >"%USERPROFILE%\appcert.log" 2>&1
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Does `appcert.log` get created when you try to run the task? What does it say?